# Why is there no exponential property of equality?

Tags: geometry

My teacher says that you can't square both sides of an equation without breaking some rules, to visualize:
x = 1
x² = 1
x = ±1
Notice how line 3 contradicts line 1, this confuses me because both sides are equal, so the square of both sides should also be equal. I would appreciate it if someone could explain.

Comment: $a=b$ implies $a^{2}=b^{2}$. I don't know what your teacher is saying.

Comment: but $x^2=1$ does not imply $x=1$.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong (or you misunderstood what they were saying). Squaring both sides of a true equation will always result in a true equation. More generally, if $F$ is **any** function and $\alpha=\beta$, then $F(\alpha)=F(\beta)$ as well (this is basically what "function" means in the first place). What is true, however, is that squaring both sides of an equation is not a **reversible** process. That is, $x=y$ implies $x^2=y^2$ but $x^2=y^2$ does not imply $x=y$. Compare this with (say) addition, where $x+a=y+a$ does imply $x=y$. (I'm only commenting since I think this is a duplicate.)

Comment: (Continuing geetha290krm's comment) …However, $a^2=b^2$ does not imply $a=b$. Implications are _one-way_.

Comment: What the teacher probably means is that squaring is no equivalence transformation. It usually changes the solution set.

Comment: But why can you not reverse it?

Comment: If you flatten two pieces of plasticine, you may get the same shape. But the original pieces may not have the same shape. So it should be obvious that not everything you do can be reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea here is that just because two squares are equal, it doesn't mean the original things were equal.  The reverse, however is true,  if two things are equal of course their squares are equal!

The danger comes when squaring both sides of an equation with unknowns, you can introduce what are called "extraneous solutions",  things don't don't actually solve the original problem.   A very simple example:

Let's say we wanted to solve for x:
$$\sqrt x=-1$$
One might think "Squaring gets rid of the root, so lets square both sides"
$$(\sqrt x)^2=(-1)^2$$
$$x=1$$

However, this is obviously false, since $\sqrt 1=1$, not $-1$!  The breakdown occurs because squaring is not a "1 to 1" function, so you can't go back and forth freely like you can with addition and multiplication, which are. (Except for multiplication by 0!

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.